# How to combine 2 SASS functions as they do almost the same thing just using a different calculation?

Tags: css, sass

I was wondering if someonce could advise me on how I could combine the SASS functions below, basically they do the same thing but one is used specifically for IE so having 2 is a waste. I've tried adding if..else statements with an additional parameter like if ( $property == 'ie' ) but with no success.

Functions:

```
// To use width, margin, padding...
@function percentageWidth( $elementWidth, $containerWidth ){
  @return $elementWidth/$containerWidth * 100%;
}

// To use *width ie6/7 workarounds
@function iePercentageWidth( $elementWidth, $containerWidth ){
  @return $elementWidth/$containerWidth - 0.5/$containerWidth * 100%;
}
```

Current CSS:

```
width: percentageWidth( 214,945 );
*width: iePercentageWidth( 214,945 );
```

I would also like to use this function on things like:

```
margin: percentageWidth( 23,945 );
```

Comment: Why not use a mixin that calculates and gives you a margin & *margin?

Comment: how can i make this mixin work for all properties and calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a general mixin you can use to create a pair of properties:

```
@mixin ieprop($name, $elementWidth, $containerWidth) {
   #{$name}: percentageWidth($elementWidth, $containerWidth);
   *#{$name}: iePercentageWidth($elementWidth, $containerWidth);
}
```

You pass the property name as the first parameter, like so:

```
.cls {
  @include ieprop('width', 214, 945);
  @include ieprop('margin', 23, 945);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
@mixin twoWidths($x, $y){
  width: percentageWidth($x, $y);
  *width: iePercentageWidth($x, $y);
}
```

Then in your stylesheet you'd call it like:

```
@include twoWidths(500,700);
```